# Directing logging depending on call context in modular monolith web application

Tags: java, slf4j

For some story, we used to have an application in microservices architecture, and all services included and used a common dependency library. It was later decided, the microservices approach wasn't justified and had more overhead than benefit, and eventually was refactored into a modular monolith. Everything is nice and solid, except for one problem. Now everything is being logged into one place, and log entries from common module are less obvious wrt which part of code called it. If previously (microservices) the structure was

```
service-a.log:
----
ServiceA: doing this
Common DB service: calling DB with x  <-- obviously called by service A
```

```
service-b.log:
----
ServiceB: doing that
Common DB service: calling DB with y <-- obviously called by service B
```

now (with monolith) we have everything in one heap

```
webapp.log:
----
ServiceA: doing this
ServiceB: doing that
Common DB service: calling DB with x  <-- called by what?
Common DB service: calling DB with y <-- called by what?
```

and this isn't ideal. Yes, I know I can track around using thread names, but it would be much more pleasant if the separation was done on file level. It's obvious how to direct service A and service B logs to separate files. But how to do it with Common DB service? Is this feasible? I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't be intrusive to the services themselves, ie that I could still keep having something simple like

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class CommonDBService { ... }
```

with no extra logging configuration logic in the service

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. This is not something you address through slf4j, you address this through the configuration of the actual logging implementation you're using.

Comment: I figured slf4j is more relevant than actual backend, because I assumed backend would have lost the context by the time it gets a message, it would only have a logger name and logged objects. And it seems the assumption was at least in part warranted, the solution is to use what slf4j calls Mapped Diagnostic Context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my googling abilities had let me down. The solution was to use Mapped Diagnostic Context, which allows associating bits of information with the thread. I put current module value into MDC by making a high priority filter, which which extracts and saves first segment of the path. How that bit of information in MDC is used to direct to specific file is logging backend-specific, but in a case with logback it's through SiftingAppender.